# How to order result by distance from the point in Overpass?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I using query which returns nearby streets. Is it possible to order this streets by distance from the point?

```
<query type="way">
    <around lat="51.15178610143037" lon="9.931640625" radius="1000"/>
    <has-kv k="highway" regv="primary|secondary|tertiary|residential"/>
</query>
<union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="down"/>
</union>
<print/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not directly within the Overpass API. You'd have to sort the streets yourself in a post-processing step.

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation on OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Print_.28out.29) you can use:

```
out qt
```

or in your case

```
<print order="quadtile"/>
```

described as *sort by quadtile index; this is roughly geographical and significantly faster than order by ids*. It's not exactly you want, but still better than sort by ids.